# Cypress clicks Angular link too early

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onclick, cypress

I have a Angular App and I'm running E2E-Tests with Cypress.
A normal Test would open the Site with `cy.visit('/')` and after the Load it starts to navigate on the site using buttons on the sidebar. The theme used for the menu is PrimeNG Ultima.

The Test runs fine on my local dev-machine, but fails in CI.
It seems like Cypress fires the click-event before Angular has registered the needed logic to handle the click on the link element.

**Is there a way to let cypress know when Angular finished its bootstraping?**
I would prefer a Solution without extra code inside the main-app but I could make changes inside the Angular Part.

I already tried the following Snippets without Success:

```js
cy.window().its('getAllAngularRootElements' as any).should('exist');
```

```js
cy.window().then(win => new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => win.requestIdleCallback(resolve)));
```

Another workaround which partially worked was listening on the pace.js progress-bar included with the PrimeNG-Theme, but it was not reliable enough for all tests.

## See also

- [Cypress Angular When Can Test Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880285/cypress-angular-when-can-test-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Chrome Debugger Protocol as described in this article [When Can The Test Click](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/when-can-the-test-click/)

The example given is

```js
it('clicks on the button when there is an event handler', () => {
  cy.visit('public/index.html')

  const selector = 'button#one'
  cy.CDP('Runtime.evaluate', {
    expression: 'frames[0].document.querySelector("' + selector + '")',
  })
    .should((v) => {
      expect(v.result).to.have.property('objectId')
    })
    .its('result.objectId')
    .then(cy.log)
    .then((objectId) => {
      cy.CDP('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', {
        objectId,
        depth: -1,
        pierce: true,
      }).should((v) => {
        expect(v.listeners).to.have.length.greaterThan(0)
      })
    })
  // now we can click that button
  cy.get(selector).click()
})
```

where cy.CDP is installed from this package [cypress-cdp](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-cdp)

---

**Retrying the click**

Another approach might be to retry the click until it has an effect.

The exact code would be app dependent, but the pattern would be

```js
const clickUntilChanged = (linkSelector, changeSelector, attempt = 0) => {

  if (attempt > 10) throw 'Something went wrong'

  cy.get(changeSelector).invoke('text')
    .then(initial => {

      cy.get(linkSelector).click()            // attempt a click  
      cy.get(changeSelector).invoke('text')
        .then(next => {
          if (initial === next) {             // no change
            cy.wait(50)                       // wait a bit then try again
            clickUntilChanged(linkSelector, changeSelector, ++attempt)
          }
          // else click was effective, just exit
        })
    })
})

clickUntilChanged('menu-item', 'page-header')
```

---

**Test retries**

Another approach is to make use of a small initial test with retries set

```js
it('tests the link click', {retries: {runMode: 10, openMode: 0}}, () => {
    cy.get('menu-item').click()
    cy.get('page-header')
      .should('have.text', 'new-page-header')  // fails and retries 
                                               // if click had no effect
})
```

---

**Just wait**

Looking at Gleb's latest article [Solve The First Click](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/solve-the-first-click/), right in the middle he just adds a hard wait to allow the event listeners to hook up.

This is probably my preferred approach given the simplicity, and who would notice an extra 1 second in a CI run.

```js
cy.visit(...)
if (!Cypress.config('isInteractive')) {   // run mode
  cy.wait(1000)
}
cy.get('menu-item').click()               // should now be functioning
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I tried the CDP part but got stuck on the way and ended up using a modified version of your retry idea. Since then it is way more stable.